# android ExoPlayer getCurrentTracks language is null why?

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have android TV application which display ExoPlayer of streaming UDP url, all is working fine about streaming and video
The problem is the audio is not available, Video play without audio, so i check the below to see the supported language for this exoplayer

```
        for (int i = 0; i < player.getCurrentTracks().getGroups().size(); i++) {

                    String format = player.getCurrentTracks().getGroups().get(i).getTrackFormat(0).sampleMimeType;
                    String lang = 
    player.getCurrentTracks().getGroups().get(i).getTrackFormat(0).language;
     player.getCurrentTracks().getGroups().get(i).getTrackFormat(0).id;
   }
```

The problem is the size of array is 2, but the language is always null for the 2 object of array, there is no language

any help to force the audio to play?

Comment: Have you verified the stream in another player, in a browser for example to ensure it actually has an audio track? If you are able to share a link to the url that would also help.

Comment: how can i test the stream in a browser ? the link is local is it useless to share it, but let me know how i can test in a browser?

Comment: It depends on the stream type but look at Shaka Player (https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com) and addd custom content, or  player test page like BitMovin (https://bitmovin.com/demos/stream-test).